# How to correctly sum a 2 column query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having a difficult time summing a column of distinct values based on a column of values, which also needs to be distinct.  For example, I have:

```
Index  PaymentID  PaymentAmt PartPmtApplied
  1        35        50          26
  2        35        50          24
  3        36        50          38
  4        36        50          12
  5        37        52          14
  6        37        52          14
  7        37        52          24
  8        38        54          37
  9        38        54          17
 10        39       100         100
```

The query I used is as follows:

```
Select sum(paymentamt) from tbl_A where paymentid = 
             (select distinct paymentsid from tbl_A);
```

So, I thought I was doing my query correct, but when I do, it still sums up every value in the PaymentAmt column, i.e. I receive a total of 564 instead of 256.

Anyone have a better way for me to find this value? Thanks in advance.

Thank you for the quick responses.  But, as someone asked, here is what I am looking for:

```
35   50
36   50
37   52
38   54
39  100
```

Sum total = 256.  So, I should be returning a single value of 256.

Comment: can you also show your desired output?

Comment: 50+50+52+54+100 = 306, can you please explain how do you count to get 256?

Comment: Bad math?  Not sure how I came up with that total, honestly.  I just added up quickly in my head and forgot one of the 50's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to sum distinct values you can just simply sum everything from a subquery that would hold only distinct values ( or distinct pairs of values ).

So you probably need

```
SELECT SUM( PaymentAmt ) FROM 
  ( SELECT PaymentAmt FROM tabl_a
    GROUP BY PaymentId, PaymentAmt ) distinct_payments;
```

This will give 306 as a result though, treating payments for id 35 and 36 as separate. If you really want to get 256, which would be sum of distinct payments without any link to ids then just use `GROUP BY PaymentAmt` instead.

Comment: Yes -> this works perfectly when I grouped by paymentid and paymentamt.  And, for the record, I did want 306 -- I guess my brain is too tired to do simple math in my head.  Thanks again.  Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can actually do it without any subquery. Just use `GROUP BY` in your query.

```
SELECT  PaymentID, SUM(PaymentAmount) TotalPayment
FROM    tabl_a
GROUP   BY PaymentID
```

This will give you unique value of `PaymentID` with its calculated total amount of `PaymentAmount`.

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/99a65/3)

OUTPUT

```
╔═══════════╦══════════════╗
║ PAYMENTID ║ TOTALPAYMENT ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════╣
║        35 ║          100 ║
║        36 ║          100 ║
║        37 ║          156 ║
║        38 ║          108 ║
║        39 ║          100 ║
╚═══════════╩══════════════╝
```

Comment: Um ... definite upvote for the SQLFiddle Demo.  That's a pretty cool link - unfortunately those were not the droids I was looking for (or the results).

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use a GROUP BY.

```
SELECT PaymentID, SUM(PaymentAmt) as PaymentTotal FROM tbl_A GROUP BY PaymentID;
```

This will pipe out a row for each unique PaymentID, with the corresponding sums of the payment amounts.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to `sum` all your `distinct amounts`, as it gets the results as

```
SELECT
  sum(TotalPayment) 
FROM
 ( SELECT  
    distinct 
    PaymentAmt TotalPayment
  FROM    
    tableName ) t
```